# How to find a sentence and a 13 digit code in a paragraph in Regex

Tags: regex

From a large paragraph, I want to extract the sentence "Updating measure to exclude the ean added from catalogue list" any word in between plus a 13 digit number (e.g: 7090056511721).

The 13 digit number is not at the end of the sentence, there could be more words after that.

Paragraph example:

> Query Opened: /* Updating measure to exclude the ean added from
> catalogue list */ Cartesian scope: ([Box].[Box].Filter( #.Name == "Box
> 1") * [LocalPricePoint].[LocalPricePoint].Filter( #.Name == "Premium") * [Gender].[Gender].Filter( #.Name == "Male") * [LocalUniverse].[LocalUniverse].Filter( #.Name == "Creator") *
> [BusinessCategory].[BusinessCategory].Filter( #.Name == "Frames") *
> [Time].[Trimester].Filter( #.Name == "22.2") * &CWV *
> [Product].[EAN].Filter(#.Name in {[7090056511721],[7090056511714]}) *
> Location.[Banner].Filter( #.Name == "SCCH1") *
> Profile.[Profile].Filter(#.Name in
> {[Premium]}));Measure.[IntNewBAStatus]=1;End Scope;

```
pattern = ('Updating measure to exclude the ean added from catalogue list')('any words in between')(\d{13})?
```

Comment: something like: https://regex101.com/r/VVldPf/1, and then check if the match contains your 13 digit number.

Comment: Maybe https://regex101.com/r/VVldPf/2?

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the pattern needed:

```
pattern = ".*(Updating measure to exclude the ean added from catalogue list).*(\d{13}).*"
```

https://regex101.com/r/VVldPf/1